# The MOUSEBUTTONDOWN command activates itself without me clicking

Tags: python, pygame

so i have started making my own game for a project and after the spaceship shoots when you click the mouse it fires again without me pressing anything and it goes on forever. I have included what i have so far below

```
from livewires import games
import pygame
games.init(screen_width = 840, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)

class Spaceship(games.Sprite):
    """Creates the Spaceship"""

    ship_image = games.load_image("spaceship.bmp")

    def __init__(self):

        super(Spaceship, self).__init__(image = Spaceship.ship_image,
                                      x = games.mouse.x,
                                      bottom = games.screen.height)
    def update(self):
        """ Move to mouse x position. """
        self.x = games.mouse.x

        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = 0

        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.right = games.screen.width
        #Makes the laser spawn on the spaceship
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                new_laser = Laser(self.x, self.y)
                games.screen.add(new_laser)

class Laser(games.Sprite):
    """Creates the laser"""
    laser_image = games.load_image("laser1.png")

    def __init__(self,spaceship_x, spaceship_y):


        super(Laser, self).__init__(image = Laser.laser_image,
                                    x = spaceship_x, y = spaceship_y,
                                    dy = -6)


#class enemy(game.Sprite):  


def main():
    """Runs the game"""
    background = games.load_image("featured-space-policy.jpg", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = background

    ship = Spaceship()
    games.screen.add(ship)
    games.mouse.is_visible = False
    games.screen.mainloop()


main()
```

Comment: you need to have another listener set up for when the mouse button is released, then stop firing.

Answer (score 0):

Just think about it,

Since you set up an event listen for `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`, so this will trigger the Laser function but **how it will stop?**,

So, you need to set up another listener for `MOUSEBUTTONUP` which will stop the firing of the laser, something like this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                new_laser = Laser(self.x, self.y)
                games.screen.add(new_laser)
            else event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                 remove_laser()#something like that, I'm not sure if it's the right method.
```